# When making Delete Jquery Ajax request, the respnonse code is 200 , but the data is not getting deleted. What could be the possible reason for this

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest, jax-rs

I am trying to make a DELETE request but it doesn't work. My code is as follows:

```
$.ajax({
    type : "DELETE",
    url : "/meds/dme-rest-api/resources/data-setup/deleteCheckList.json?" + $.param({"checkListId":currentCheckListId}),

    headers : {authToken : '${TOKEN}'},
    cache : false,
    success : function(data){
                 console.log(data);
            }
    });
```

The response which I get is : {"errorMessage":"","success":true}
But the data is not getting deleted. What is the reason behind this ?
Please let me know if I should some extra information.

**Update** The API is as follows:

```
@DELETE
@Path("deleteCheckList.json")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response deleteCheckList(@HeaderParam(value = RestHttpHeaderNames.AUTH_TOKEN) String authToken,
        @FormParam(value = "checkListId") int iCheckListId) throws Exception, SQLException {

    User user = UserManagement.getInstance().get(authToken);
    String sCompanyNo = user.getCompanyNo();
    int iEmployeeNo = user.getEmployeeNo();

    return RestUtils.getNoCacheResponseBuilder(Response.Status.OK).entity(
            DataSetupManager.newInstance().deleteCheckList(sCompanyNo, iEmployeeNo, iCheckListId).toString())
            .build();
}
```

Comment: Is `deleteCheckList.json` a literal json file?  If it is, that's not going to work.  A json file has no logic around parsing inputs and processing updates.  Just like requesting a static html file, that's all you get.  The file.

Comment: Otherwise if this is an actual endpoint that does some processing, you're going to have to debug the endpoint to find out why it is not doing what you expect it to be doing.

Comment: Nope, it's not a json file. It's path for the API. I'll update that in the original question in a minute.

Comment: @j08691 Why the type should be GET or POST ? My goal here is to delete the information.

Comment: Didn't see your rest tag until your update. Looked like you were calling just a normal server script

Comment: Do some debugging. Debugging is a task that every developer must learn how to do well. You're asking us why an operation within a complex system is not working. There are a lot of moving parts to this system. We don't have access to all these moving parts. This is a problem where you will need to break down the system (or code) into individual parts and find out which parts are working as expected and which ones aren't. Check all the variable values and find out which ones are expected and which ones aren't.

Answer (score 0):

Your java method always returns Response OK.

You should delete what you need to delete, which may fail. If it fails, return a status that is not OK

Comment: How do I do this? The java code is not written by me.

Comment: @user45437 by getting the backend changed. If you ask the backend to do something, and it replies with "yeah. Done that" but didn’t do what you asked it to do, then it failed.